# QGIS Georeferencer Failing to Compute Transform

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I've been using QGIS for quite some time, but have encountered a problem that I can't seem to resolve. I am georeferencing an aerial photograph. I have established ample GCP points. After a fresh install of QGIS on a particular computer, the georeferencer works perfectly and provides the correct output. After the initial run, the georeferencer fails to work on any dataset, always returning the error message "Failed to compute GCP transform.  Transform is not solvable." Picking new GCP points has no effect whatsoever. Changing images has no effect. The georeferencer works for the first run on any computer, and then quits. I tried re-installing QGIS, but the problem persists despite the new installation. It seems to me that QGIS is holding on to some temporary data that is crashing the georeferencer application. Any ideas?

Comment: Im having the same problem. My memory is not full. I'm stuck, Maybe it is because my residue is too high. My coordinates are correct[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVbnX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVbnX.png)

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem for a while, uninstalled and reinstalled QGIS several times, but actually turned out to be an easy fix, I unchecked the 'Set Target Resolution' in the transformation settings window. 
My work doesnt require a target resolution so was an easy work around however, I'm still not sure what the route of the problem is.

Comment: My "set target resolution" is already unchecked

Comment: I found that in some cases it works with that checked in other cases it works if unchecked with apparently no reason. I guess it's a bug workaround.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the very same problem today with same error message. After many frustrating attempts I finally figured out: Not enough space on external HD where  computed raster was supposed to be saved.

Comment: You are a life savor

Answer (score 4):

I found that both datasets should be in the same coordinate system, epsg:25832. That solved the problem.
This GDAL command solved the problem:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:25832 oJostedal_k3_2016_ps.tif oJostedal_k3_2016_ps_25832.tif
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same issue, and found that one solution was to actually designate an output raster file name, rather than rely on the system generated default. I also tried it a couple of other times and found I was unable to overwrite a previous output file, so bear that in mind as well. I didn't have to switch to .tiff for my input, and was able to still use .png. For me, the issue seems to stem from the output file name.

Answer (score 2):

Check the encoding of your point coordinates in column DEST X & DEST Y.

-1.67022e is NOT exaclty -16.702208, but that's what got saved, so just check for errors there.

If you see some entries that look strange like the one above, deselect them then re-save your point file with a new name.

Go ahead and rerun Georeferencing. It should work smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by changing input image from jpg format to tif format.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. It solved when I set the "Compression" to `None`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. It solved when I set the "Compression" to LZW or deflate. I think the due to less hard disk space the complier was not able to process the dataset therefore after compressing the tiff file the jpeg image was successfully georeferenced.

Answer (score 1):

Having spaces in the output raster file name was the issue for me. Changing the place it was saved to an empty folder solved it.

Answer (score 1):

To solve problem, in georeference, enter the transformation settings and in the target CRS set the coordinate system the same as the map coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

So "Failed to compute GCP transform. Transform is not solvable" appears to be a general error message; multiple things can make the transform fail. You may want to check all the issues above.

Here's one: "Set target resolution" (i.e. make the warped image's pixels match the base image 1:1) appears to make the transform fail if the image getting warped extends beyond the base (i.e. target) image. I Photoshopped a huge margin onto the base image and then it worked just fine.

Comment: Note to self: Also check dumb little things like the files getting deleted, moved, or renamed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the Transformation type  in Transformation Setting from "Linear" to "Helmert"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too on version 3.28.3. Some times it worked some time it failed with the transform failed message.  Solution for me was the <file_name_modified.tiff> already existed in the folder I was saving to.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem, Changing coordinate system in Georeferenced solved the problem.